# Merge two Flows in Room

Tags: android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to query two different tables and merge the result in one `Flow`. Both Entities are implementing the same Interface `Listable`.
My Repository function:

```
    override suspend fun fetchAllItems(): Flow<List<Listable>> = withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        val trainSearches = async { trainSearchDao.getAllTrainSearches() }
        val stationSearches = async { stationSearchDao.getAllStationSearches() }
        merge(stationSearches.await(), trainSearches.await())
    }
```

The call in my `ViewModel`:

```
    private fun loadAllItems() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _uiState.update { it.copy(savedItems = homeRepo.fetchAllItems()) }
        }
    }
```

My Composable:

```
(...)
val savedItems by uiState.savedItems.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
(...)
Timber.d("AllItems: $savedItems")
(...)
```

Which results in two Log-Statements:

```
2023-10-09 18:37:50.615 31911-31911 FavListUIKt$FavListUI      D  AllItems: [TrainSearch(id=1, type=ICE, number=78, name=), TrainSearch(id=2, type=ICE, number=78, name=)]
2023-10-09 18:37:50.733 31911-31911 FavListUIKt$FavListUI      D  AllItems: [StationSearch(id=1, station=Station(id=ABC, extId=1, name=AB, type=ST), searchDay=SearchDay(type=TODAY, weekday=null), searchTime=SearchTime(type=NOW, time=null, hoursInAdvance=null), meansOfTransports=[ICE, IC_EC, IR_D, RE_RB, S_BAHN, BUS, SHIP, U_BAHN, TRAM, AST], name=), StationSearch(id=2, station=Station(id=ABC, extId=1, name=AB, type=ST), searchDay=SearchDay(type=NEXT_DAY_OF_THE_WEEK, weekday=MONDAY), searchTime=SearchTime(type=EXACT, time=07:00, hoursInAdvance=null), meansOfTransports=[RE_RB, S_BAHN, BUS, SHIP, U_BAHN, TRAM, AST], name=), StationSearch(id=3, station=Station(id=ABC, extId=1, name=AB, type=ST), searchDay=SearchDay(type=TOMORROW, weekday=null), searchTime=SearchTime(type=LATER, time=null, hoursInAdvance=8), meansOfTransports=[RE_RB, S_BAHN, BUS, SHIP, U_BAHN, TRAM, AST], name=zurück)]
```

Why does the repository coroutines trigger the ui to redraw?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, when I change the type of my functions from `Flow<List<Listable>>` to `List<Listable>` it works just fine. I think I'll leave it that way.